# Django queryset indexing shuffle around and doesn't remember my changes

Tags: python, django, database

**Background**

I have model C inherits B

In C, it has just normal charField, nullBooleanField and foreign keys.

```
class C(B):
  uid = UUIDField(unique=True)
  x = models.ForeignKey(X, to_field='uid')

  y = models.ForeignKey(Y, to_field='uid', null=True)

  z = models.TextField()
  u = models.ForeignKey(U, null=True)
  foo = models.NullBooleanField(default=False)
```

In B, it has bunch of dateField like below

```
class B(models.Model):
  date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  date_deactivated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_index=True, 
    help_text='Set to false if the instance is deleted.')
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

None of those classes has meta order specified.

**The problem**

When I was in a shell_plus, I assigned `C.objects.all()` to a variable called `cs`, then I can see `cs[0]`, `cs[1]`, `cs[2]` and `cs[3]`. There are only 4 records. Now I want to change one nullBooleanField to false/true. I did `cs[1].foo = true` and `cs[1].save()`

I would expect 4 records are in the same order as when I fetched them and the second record's foo field is updated.

The actual result is, for some reasons, the second record is moved to the back of the list, and it doesn't remember my changes.

For example, in the beginning, 4 records are R1, R2, R3, R4 and R2.foo is false. After the assigning foo to true for the second record as I describe above, the result is R1, R3, R4, R2 and R2.foo is still false.

The workaround seems to be assigning cs[1] to a variable first then change the variable. It would be nice the know why.

Is there anything in Django that can cause queryset result to be rearranged?

**Edit**
does each queryset[index] cause a database hit?

Comment: That is indeed usually the case with MySQL. If you do not specify an order, the database can produce results in *any* order it likes. Furthermore typically there is some correlation with the last *modification* time (although that is not always the case).

Comment: I'm using postgres, is it the same?

Comment: The fact that `foo` is still `False` seems to suggest something is strange about the field.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PostgreSQL, but I think usually the workings of the database engine (that can very as well) are rather similar. The point is, if you do not specify an order, then I think you better *not* assume anything on the order in which you will retrieve objects. A database has the freedom to order it in any way it likes, and typically the query itself has some impact, since databases are optimized to return the results as fast as possible. So sometimes returning them in a different order can be faster (since for example an index can be exploited).

Comment: I'm not too bothered with the reorder. But not remembering my changes is annoying.

Comment: well that is probably because something is wrong with the `foo` field (in Django). Can you share the (relevant parts of the) `C` model?

Comment: Sure, Updated..

Comment: Ha, hold on, this is a queryset, so if you write `cs[1]`, you make a fetch, so if you write `cs[1].foo = True`, then you change the object, but you do not save it. If you then write `cs[1].save()`, you make another fetch, load the *old* object, and save that again, but the old fetch is thus lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**: `qs` is a `QuerySet`. If you write `qs[i]`, you actually make *another query* (one that looks like `<OLD QUERY> LIMIT 1 OFFSET i`), so you fetch the *i*-th element from the old queryset into memory.

The point is that if you write `qs[i]` twice, you make two *independent* fetches. If we thus write two `qs[1]`s, we obtain two *different* objects. If you thus perform a `qs[1].save()`, you make an independent fetch, load the object from the database, and immediately save it. But previous modifications that have not been saved will have no effect.

If you thus want to make a change to an object, you need to use a reference, so write:

```
# will change the second element
cs1 = cs[1]     # we fetch the object, and store it in cs1
cs1.foo = True  # we change the object
cs1.save()      # we save the object
```

instead of:

```
# will *NOT* change the second element
cs[1].foo = True  # load object, change it, but throws the object away
cs[1].save()      # loads the object again, and save it, with no change
```

The fact that the order of the objects changes between two queries is common in many database engines (well usually given some row is updated, or even if a new row is created). It depends on the indexes a database has how the rows are obtained, and often rows that are changed will occur as last (or first) row in the result set, although if you do not specify the order, usually there are no *strong* guarantees how the result will be ordered.